# Change value to others and Sum value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a question to change some names to other and then sum value. Sorry for the poor title, please change for better one.
I will explain here.
Here is my data:

```
ColA     ColB   ColC   ColD    ColE
APPLE    1      A      100      30 
APPLE    1      B      200      20
APPLE    1      C      100      50
APPLE    1      D       50     100
APPLE    1      E       50     100
APPLE    2      C       50     100 
BANANA   1      A       30      50
BANANA   1      C       20      20
BANANA   3      B      100     100
BANANA   3      C       50      50
BANANA   3      D      100     200
```

In `ColC`, `A` and `B` are change to `X`, and then sum `ColD` and `ColE`.
If `ColC` is `C`, `D`, and `E`, it should be `Y`, and then sum.
The result is like following:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
APPLE    1       X       300     50
APPLE    1       Y       200    250
APPLE    2       Y        50    100
BANANA   1       X        30     50
BANANA   1       Y        20     20
BANANA   3       X       100    100
BANANA   3       Y       150    250
```

*DATA*:

```
dt <- fread("ColA     ColB   ColC   ColD    ColE
APPLE    1      A      100      30 
APPLE    1      B      200      20
APPLE    1      C      100      50
APPLE    1      D       50     100
APPLE    1      E       50     100
APPLE    2      C       50     100 
BANANA   1      A       30      50
BANANA   1      C       20      20
BANANA   3      B      100     100
BANANA   3      C       50      50
BANANA   3      D      100     200
")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a data table (due to `fread`) then here is an idea.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, ColC := ifelse(ColC %in% c('A', 'B'), 'X', 'Y')
   ][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(ColA, ColB, ColC)][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>      ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE
> 1:  APPLE    1    X  300   50
> 2:  APPLE    1    Y  200  250
> 3:  APPLE    2    Y   50  100
> 4: BANANA    1    X   30   50
> 5: BANANA    1    Y   20   20
> 6: BANANA    3    X  100  100
> 7: BANANA    3    Y  150  250
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Some basic `dplyr`:

First, use `case_when` to change the variable, then group and sum.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  mutate(ColC = case_when(ColC %in% c("A", "B") ~ "X", TRUE ~ "Y")) %>% 
  group_by(ColA, ColB, ColC) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   ColA, ColB [?]
>     ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE
>    <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
> 1  APPLE     1     X   300    50
> 2  APPLE     1     Y   200   250
> 3  APPLE     2     Y    50   100
> 4 BANANA     1     X    30    50
> 5 BANANA     1     Y    20    20
> 6 BANANA     3     X   100   100
> 7 BANANA     3     Y   150   250
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt$ColC <- plyr::revalue(dt$ColC,c("A"="x","B"="x","C"="Y","D"="Y","E"="Y"))

dt %>% 
     group_by(ColA,ColB,ColC) %>% 
                               summarise_all(sum)
```